# Smooth transition between logos

Tags: jquery

I have a sticky header which I added custom code to so that it would change the image logo when you start scrolling down the page. I want the logos to have a smooth transition from one to the other but I'm not having any luck. Here's the code I'm using.

```
    jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(window.scrollY === 0) {
    $('.x-navbar .x-brand img').attr('src', 'http://test.unknowndesign.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/UNKNOWN.svg');
}  
else
{
    $('.x-navbar  .x-brand img').attr('src', 'http://test.unknowndesign.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/U.svg').fadeIn(200);
}
})
});
```

Comment: Use images preloading. Now when you apply new source only then browser will try to fetch image. Also for `fadeIn` to work element must be hidden initialy

Comment: Try to load the two logos, one visible and the other hidden and play with the visibility of each maybe? Look for carousel with fade transition it's the same idea I think : lot of pictures in the same place that disapear and appear

Comment: @Justinas How do I use images preloading? Could you give me a code example?

Comment: @MickaelLeger could you please show me how that code would look?

Comment: @Jacqui look this link, somehting like this with logo and you change the trigger to change your logo on scroll maybe? https://codepen.io/danielguillan/pen/duiAq

Comment: @Jacqui I anwser you, it's not a trigger "onscroll" but is it the effect you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a fadeout (or hide/other function that hides the element) effect first on the image element. Since the element is already visable fadein doesn't do anything. You are just changing an attribute.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if(window.scrollY === 0) {
            $('.x-navbar .x-brand img').attr('src', 'http://test.unknowndesign.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/UNKNOWN.svg');
        }  
        else
        {
             $('.x-navbar  .x-brand img').fadeOut(200).attr('src', 'http://test.unknowndesign.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/U.svg').fadeIn(200);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("img").on("click", function() {
  $('.one').css("opacity") == 1 ? $('.one').css("opacity", 0) : $('.one').css("opacity", 1);
  $('.two').css("opacity") == 0 ? $('.two').css("opacity", 1) : $('.two').css("opacity", 0);
});
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

img + img { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/400/300" class="one" alt="Fill Murray">
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/300" class="two" alt="Place Cage">
```

Here is an example of what you could do as "fading" effect, now change the trigger to do the same on scroll.
Don't forget the CSS with `img {transition: opacity .5s ease-in;}`, that's your "smooth" transition !

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: `$('.one').css("opacity") == 1 ? $('.one').css("opacity", 0) : $('.one').css("opacity", 1);` why not toggle it like this. Doing a modulo on a counter looks like bad practice to me.

Comment: I edit my anwser, ty. It was more for the fade effect but I should have done it better for sure